# Particle number in the BCS theory

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

I don't really understand why the nonconserved particle number in the BCS theory isn't a problem. I read in the Tinkham book that it isn't a problem since the particle number is huge.

The fluctuation of the particle number N is given by
$$(\delta N)^2 = \langle\Psi_{BCS}  |(N-\bar{N})^2 |\Psi_{BCS} \rangle $$ and for $N \rightarrow \infty$, $(\delta N)^2 \rightarrow \infty$.
However the fractional fluctuations $\delta N/ \bar{N} $ goes to zero for a lage particle number, i.e. for $N \rightarrow \infty$, $\delta N/ \bar{N} \rightarrow 0 $.
I don't get that argument, why aren't the absolute fluctuations the ones who matter, rather than the fractional ones?

Comment: The total particle number *is* conserved provided you include both the particle number of the quasiparticles (which do not have a sharp particle number) with the  (also non-sharp) particle number of the condensate. In particlular you must include the dynamics of the condenstate when coupling to electromagnetism.

Comment: but in the ground state there is only the condensate, so the particle number is not conserved there?

Comment: The particle number is not *sharp* -- i.e  the BCS  ground state with a definte supeconducting phase is in a *superposition* of different particle numbers.   If you take instead a superposition of states with different order-parameter phases then you can have a gound state that is an eigenstate of particle number. The ground state particle number  is quite a different issue than number *non-conservation*. (Non)-conservatiom  requires *dynamics*, and so coupling to states other than the ground state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the BCS ground state is easiest to describe as a state with no definite particle number. This state can then be expressed as a superposition of states with definite particle number, but this is usually not necessary. We can do all calculations with the ordinary BCS ground state and just assume the state has $\bar N = \langle \Psi_{\rm BCS}|N|\Psi_{\rm BCS}\rangle$ particles in it on average. There will be fluctuations in the particle number, but these are much smaller than the particle number itself so it doesn't change our approximation.

This is very analogous to a coherent electromagnetic field. For a single mode with frequency $\omega$, such a field is an eigenstate of the electric field operator (in axial gauge):
$$ E = \dot A \sim \sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2}} \,(a - a^\dagger) $$
but not of the photon number operator
$$ N =  a^\dagger a \;.$$
However, we can still approximate that on average, there will be $\bar N$ photons, where
$$\bar N = \langle N \rangle = \frac{1}{2\omega}\langle E^2 \rangle\;.$$
For a strong field, $\bar N$ will be large and the fluctuations will be proportionally small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit confused, so the absolute fluctuations $\delta N / \bar{N}$ go to infinity for $N \rightarrow \infty$. I know that the absoulte fluctiuations are $\sim \bar{N}^{1/2}$, so if $N \rightarrow \infty$, they are getting huge (but are still smaller than N). Why isn't it a problem that the fluctuations are huge?

Comment: @Motionx Nothing can be *huge* or not in absolute terms - everything in physics is measured in comparison to something else. When you say *huge* you mean that it is big in comparison to the numbers that we encounter in out everyday life - but these are irrelevant. The relevant number is the total number of electrons in the piece of metal, which is of the order of the Avogadro constant. The number of particles in teh condensate has the same order.